# Querying Two Tables For Duplicate Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure which moves (or ought to) records from one table to another. However I now want to create a procedure that checks the data in 'TableA' against the data in 'TableB'

```
SELECT A.Num, B.Num
FROM TableA AS A 
LEFT JOIN TableB AS B ON A.Num = B.Num
WHERE B.Num IS NULL
```

Basically, I want to pull out any number which isn't in 'TableB'  but is in 'TableA', is a LEFT JOIN the way to do this? I have been unsuccessful in locating missing files so far, and I have removed some to form a test case.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. You only need `SELECT A.Num` though, no need to select `B.Num`, it's going to be `NULL`.

Comment: Yes, left join is the way to do it.  Your query looks fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a [`not exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184297%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT  *   
FROM TableA A  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *      
                  FROM TableB B
                  WHERE A.NUM = B.NUM);
```

or [`not in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx):

```
SELECT  *   
FROM TableA A  
WHERE A.NUM not in (SELECT B.NUM
                  FROM TableB B);
```

Comment: Thnx, came here a bit late .

Comment: Helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Num from TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT Num from TableB
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from tableA
where id not in (select id from tableB)
```

or

```
select * from tableA a
left join tableB b on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from tableA
where id in (select id from tableB);
```

Answer (score 1):

Finding duplicates between two table

```
select table1.column_name, count(*) from table_name table1
inner join table_name table2
ON table1.coumn_name = table2.column_name;
```

ex:

```
SELECT u.username  FROM users u
INNER JOIN src_users ud
ON u.username = ud.username;
```

Finding duplicates in single table

```
select username, count(*) from users group by username having count(*) >1;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have any key then use something like this

`select sno,sname from proda group by sno, sname having count(*)>1  union  select sno,sname from basea group by sno, sname having count(*)>1`