# find duplicate between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, oracle10g

I have 2 tables say A And B with one extra column in table A.
I want to find duplicate records of table A which exists in table b. If found i want to update table A 's column with the flag that it contains record in table B also. There is no Primary key I have in both the tables.
 So far I have tried following query with union all.

```
Select * from (
Select rownum over (partition by  ename,enum order by enum) r ,* from
(Select *from a
Union all
Select * from B) data
)d where r>1
```

its not working and I am stucked. Its an oracle query.. In the same query I want to update the table A column say flg to 1 if all the columns are matched to table B ,else 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885789/querying-two-tables-for-duplicate-values

Comment: To find rows which exist in both tables you should use `INTERSECT` instead of `UNION`. To run your Update better use `EXISTS` as proposed by @sagi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question lacks a lot of information, but if I understood you correctly, you can use `EXISTS()`:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.YourFlag = 1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b
             WHERE a.ename = b.ename and a.enum = b.enum)
```

I assumed by your query that the relations between the tables are `ename,enum` ? If thats not the case, change the where clause inside the sub query to your relations.